# Swift - Saving Int to Core Data only works once

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Here's how I'm saving the data

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Theme", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let themeObj = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    themeObj.setValue(num, forKey: "themeNumber")

    var error: NSError?
    if !managedContext.save(&error)
    {
        println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }
```

And then loading it

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Theme")
    var resultArr = [NSManagedObject]()
    var error: NSError?

    let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [NSManagedObject]?

    if let results = fetchedResults
    {
        resultArr = results
    }
    else
    {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }


    theme = resultArr[0].valueForKey("themeNumber") as Int
```

My data model is just the entity Theme with one attribute, themeNumber which is an Integer 16. If I delete the app from the simulator, it loads the correct theme. However, if I change it and run it again... nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use setValue. Typically you would do something like this:

```
themeObj.themeNumber = num
```

So to fix your problem, you need to actually update the core data object. I just realized that you probably didn't set the themeNumber by the property because you don't have the NSManagedObject subclass setup for your entity. I'll write try to write the fix for how you have it setup.

```
theme = resultArr[0] as NSManagedObject
theme.setValue(num, forKey: "themeNumber")
if !managedContext.save(&error)
{
    println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
}
```

After you save it, see if it has the new value that you are looking for.

Comment: Change the value passed into num and run the application again. So I'm changing the value to be stored. Nothing happens, aka the value doesn't get updated. It says the same.

Comment: I think the problem is that it's not updating the first one. It's simply adding another and then the 0th index hasn't changed.

Comment: Yup... that fixed it. Thanks for helping though!

Comment: Yep you beat me to it. You were making a new one each time instead of changing your first one.